# WinForm TreeView nodes are empty despite having a DataSource to object-relational list

Tags: winforms, data-binding, telerik, treeview, treenode

In my Telerik WinForms application, I'm able to bind a TreeView to a Well object in my application through object-relational binding as such:

```
this.wellTreeView = new RadTreeView();

BindingList<Well> wells = new BindingList<Well>() { well };

this.wellTreeView.DataSource = wells;
this.wellTreeView.DisplayMember = "name\\name\\name";
this.wellTreeView.ChildMember = "wells\\layers\\items";
```

This binding works and I am able to view the TreeView hierarchy and select the nodes in the form. However, when trying to get the nodes in code, the`wellTreeView` is empty (0 nodes) and throws an `Index out of range error`
in:

```
// this line should get the root node, i.e. the Well at top level
RadTreeNode node = wellTreeView.Nodes[0];
```

My Well class is defined like so:

```
public class Well
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public List<Layer> layers {get; set;}
}
```

```
public class Layer
{
    public string name {get; set;};
    public List<Item> items {get; set;}
}
```

```
public class Item
{
    public string name {get; set;};
    public decimal length {get; set;}
}
```

I don't understand why the `wellTreeView` is empty without any nodes despite being able to view the tree in the form.

I've posted this on the
[Telerik forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radtreeview-binds-to-object-relational-data-and-can-see-the-treeview-but-the-tree-and-nodes-are-empty) too

Thank you so much, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Telerik team also provided a solution that requires me to initialise `BindingContext` when building the controls programmatically:

```
this.wellTreeView = new RadTreeView();
this.wellTreeView.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```

[Telerik forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radtreeview-binds-to-object-relational-data-and-can-see-the-treeview-but-the-tree-and-nodes-are-empty)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by calling the `LoadElementTree()` on the TreeView as such:

```
BindingList<Well> wells = new BindingList<Well>() { well };

this.wellTreeView.DataSource = wells;
this.wellTreeView.DisplayMember = "name\\name\\name";
this.wellTreeView.ChildMember = "wells\\layers\\items";

this.wellTreeView.LoadElementTree();
```